# WSUS Email notification

Tags: smtp, wsus

Can i use gmail as SMTP server for wsus ?

Answer (score 5):

Sure - you'll need create a user account for it and use authenticated SMTP, but there's no reason it wouldn't work.

In WSUS, Under Options->Email Notifications, this screen has all the configuration options you should need to set up sending through gmail. For details, see the "Outgoing Mail Server" section on [this](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13287) page. Also, don't forget to tick the "authentication" box and provide your username/password.

[image]

Comment: didn't work is there a custom setting ?

Comment: See my above edits.

Comment: if i set port to 465 it give :System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out.
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.BaseApi.SoapExceptionProcessor.DeserializeAndThrow(SoapException soapException)
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.DatabaseAccess.AdminDataAccessProxy.SendTestEmail(String emailLanguage, String smtpUserName, String senderEmailAddress, String smtpHostName, Int32 smtpPort, String recipients)
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.BaseApi.EmailNotificationConfiguration.SendTestEmail()
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.UI.SnapIn.Dialogs.EmailNotificationSettingsDialo

Comment: if i set port to 587:

System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 209.85.229.109:587
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.BaseApi.SoapExceptionProcessor.DeserializeAndThrow(SoapException soapException)
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.DatabaseAccess.AdminDataAccessProxy.SendTestEmail(String emailLanguage, String smtpUse